# Passing parameter from the user to maven via Jenkins parameterized build

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins job that is parametrized with an svn revision number, called ***param.svn.revision***, entered by a user.
During the execution, I want to launch a maven command like :

```
clean package -Dsvn.revision=$param.svn.revision
```

I tried a lot of thing instead of *$param.svn.revision*, like *${param.svn.revision}*, *"$param.svn.revision"*, *"%param.svn.revision"*,... but nothing worked.

What have I to do to make it work ?

Thanks a lot,

Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is an invalid shell expansion. Shell doesn't expect dots within variable names. You should remove the dots in the param name in order to successfully use it.